# Gson - every attribute as string

Tags: java, json, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a connection to `DocumentDB` by `Azure` and I'm saving an object into the database.

My object is an instance of class `Car`.

```
public class Car {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Car(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

To store an object to `DocumentDB` as document, you have to create a json string from the object.

The problem is when calling `new Gson().toJson(new Car(15, "Audi"));`.

It will return `"{"id":15,"name":"Audi"}"`.
But this format is not acceptable from `DocumentDB` SDK. It throws a JSON exception, because it expects following format:

`"{"id":"15","name":"Audi"}"`.

My question is if `Gson` is capable to "surround" every attribute with quotes and how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `id` member into a `String` type.

BTW, looking at Gson documentation, I don't see any option to convert automatically numbers into quoted string.

Comment: That is true, either to change it to String or surround every primitive type with quotes.